# Identify Which Label was Clicked in jsPlumb

Tags: jsplumb

To manipulate **labeled** graphs, I think I need to add an additional property on each label of jsPlumb connections. For example, when I click on a connection label, even if source and target points can be deduced from label id (or attributes) I cannot know which type of edge was clicked.

Merely changing jsPlumb graph is not enough because there are underyling data structures represented by jsPlumb graphics. Codes using jsPlumb.ready and jsPlumb.bind are already well implemented and work fine.

```
var newConn = jsPlumb.connect({ source: from, target: to,
  endpoint: epStyle, detachable: false,
  anchor: "Continuous", connector: ["StateMachine", { curviness: 20}],
  paintStyle: lineSt, hoverPaintStyle: lineHoverSt,
  overlays: [
    ["Arrow", { width: 10, length: 10, foldback: 1, location: 0.25,
     id: "arrow_" + from + to + 1}],
    ["Arrow", { width: 10, length: 10, foldback: 1, location: 0.75,
     id: "arrow_" + from + to + 2}],
    ["Label",
      { label: relation.name, id: "label_" + from + to + rel_id, cssClass: "edgeLabel"}
      // Any additional property here?
    ]
  ]
});

//Or add property here?
newConn.type = SOME_EDGE_TYPE;

jsPlumb.ready(function () {
  jsPlumb.bind("click", function (c) {
    jsPlumb.detach(c);
  });
  jsPlumb.bind("beforeDetach", function (conn) {
    return confirm(
      "Are you sure you want to disconnect ["
      + conn.sourceId + "=>" + conn.targetId + "]?");
  });
});
```

Comment: So do you want to get the endpoints(edge) when a label is clicked ?

Comment: ...And "edge type" (as in labeled graphs)

Comment: It could've been much better if jsPlumb.connect returned the edge (connection) object. Then endpoints and additional edge type can be referenced like this: var newConn = jsPlumb.connect(...); newConn.type (...)

Comment: Do you want the connection object when label is clicked?

Comment: Not when it's clicked but when it's created. If I could add some additional attribute after calling the constructor that'd be great.

Comment: When a connection is created you want to add some extra properties to it. is it so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45908/discussion-between-pruthvi-bharadwaj-and-jeffrey-goines)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event **jsPlumbConnection** to get notified when a new connection is created:

```
jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function(ci) {
            console.log(ci.connection);
            console.log(ci.sourceId+" is connected to "+ci.targetId);
});
```

In order to manipulate jsPlumb connection refer [API Document](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#Connection).

The ci(Connection Info.) object consists of following data:

1. connection - the newly established Connection.
2. source - the source element in the Connection
3. sourceEndpoint - the source Endpoint in the Connection.
4. sourceId - the ID of the source element.
5. target - the target element in the Connection.
6. targetEndpoint - the target Endpoint in the Connection.
7. targetId - the ID of the target element.

Comment: Yes, but as per the question, how does one get a reference to the **Label** from the connection?